# В React форме сделать POST используя FETCH и вывести данные формы в таблицу

Tags: reactjs, post, форма, fetch

В React форме сделать POST используя FETCH и вывести данные формы в таблицу.
Имею некую форму

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormErrors } from './FormErrors';
import Select from './Select';
import Radio from './Radio';
import Table from './Table';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            date: '',
            forecasts: [],
            loading: true,
            data: [],
            items: [],
            hits: [],
            tdata:'',
            name: '',
            checkbox: false,
            radio: '',
            formErrors: { email: '', password: '', name: '', checkbox: '' },
            emailValid: false,
            passwordValid: false,
            checkboxValid: false,
            formValid: false
        }
         fetch('api/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ forecasts: data });
                console.log('getF= ' + this.state.forecasts)
            });
    }

    handleUserInput = (e) => {
        let { name, value, type, checked } = e.target
        /* if (type === 'select') {
             value = [...selectedOptions].map(o => o.value)
         }*/
        if (type === 'checkbox') {
            value = checked
        }
        this.setState({ [name]: value },
            () => { this.validateField(name, value) });
    }

    validateField(fieldName, value) {
        let fieldValidationErrors = this.state.formErrors;
        let emailValid = this.state.emailValid;
        let passwordValid = this.state.passwordValid;
        let nameValid = this.state.nameValid;
        let checkboxValid = this.state.checkboxValid;

        switch (fieldName) {
            case 'email':
                emailValid = value.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i);
                fieldValidationErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : ' is invalid';
                break;
            case 'password':
                passwordValid = value.length >= 6;
                fieldValidationErrors.password = passwordValid ? '' : ' is too short';
                break;
            case 'name':
                nameValid = value.length >= 2 && value.match(/^([а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z])+$/i);
                fieldValidationErrors.name = nameValid ? '' : 'заполнено не верно';
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                checkboxValid = value
                fieldValidationErrors.checkbox = checkboxValid ? '' : 'Подтвердите согласие на обработку данных';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        this.setState({
            formErrors: fieldValidationErrors,
            emailValid: emailValid,
            passwordValid: passwordValid,
            nameValid: nameValid,
            checkboxValid: checkboxValid
        }, this.validateForm);
    }

    validateForm() {
        this.setState({ formValid: this.state.emailValid && this.state.passwordValid && this.state.nameValid && this.state.checkboxValid });
    }

    errorClass(error) {
        return (error.length === 0 ? '' : 'has-error');
    }


     handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('api/users', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: e.target.name.value,
                email: e.target.email.value,
                password: e.target.password.value,
                radio: e.target.radio.value,
                checkbox: e.target.checkbox.checked,
                select: e.target.select.value
            })
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
                this.setState({ forecasts: data})  
            });    
    };
    handleInputChange = (e) => {
        let input = e.target;
        let name = e.target.name;
        let email = e.target.email;
        let radio = e.target.radio;
        console.log(name)
        let value = input.value;

        this.setState({
            [email]: value,
            [name]: value,
           [radio]: value
        })
    };
    render() {
        return (

            <form className="demoForm" id="formElem" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <h2>Форма регистрации</h2>

                <div className="panel panel-default"  >
                    <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />
                </div>
                <div className={`form-group ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.email)}`}>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" required className="form-control" name="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className={`form-group ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.password)}`}>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>

                <div className={`form-group ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.name)}`}>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Введите Имя</label>
                    <input className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} placeholder="Имя" />
                </div>
                <div className={`form-group ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.checkbox)}`}>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkbox} onChange={this.handleUserInput} />Согласие на обработку перчональных данных</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Select />
                    <Radio />

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Sign up</button>
                <div>
                    <Table items={this.state.forecasts} className='table' />
                </div>

            </form>

              )
    }
}
export default Form;
```

Имею компонент Table:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Radio</th>
                        <th>Checkbox</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.items.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.id} >
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.email}</td>
                                <td>{item.password}</td>
                                <td>{item.name}</td>
                                <td>{item.select}</td>
                                <td>{item.radio}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}
export default Table;
```

При запуске приложения срабатывает GET и все данные пользователей выводятся в таблицу. Затем при заполнении формы и нажатии Button вылетают ошибки, при этом данные записываются в БД но строка не добавляется.
Что не так подскажите? Я совсем новичок.

> Table.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.items.map is not a
>   function
>       at Table.render (Table.js:19)
>       at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7873)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7850)
>       at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8225)
>       at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
>       at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
>       at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10366)
>       at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11014)
>       at performWork (react-dom.development.js:10967)
>       at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:10878)
>       at scheduleWorkImpl (react-dom.development.js:10732)
>       at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:10689)
>       at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:6212)
>       at Form../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState
>   (react.development.js:237)
>       at Form.js:192

Answer (score 2):

Итак, начнем, первая ошибка - это привязка метода в рендеринге:

```
<form className="demoForm" id="formElem" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

Я бы сказал, что это не лучшее место для привязки метода. [Использование `Function.prototype.bind` в методе `render()`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-render) создаёт новую функцию при каждом рендере компонента, что может повлиять на производительность. Также, следует знать, что [использование стрелочной функции в `render()`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) создаёт новую функцию при каждой отрисовке компонента, что может нарушать оптимизацию. Поэтому хорошим решением будет вынести привязку в конструктор:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Затем в форму просто передадим наш метод (функцию):

```
<form className="demoForm" id="formElem" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
```

Дальше добавим примитивную проверку прилетающей пропсы `items` для компонента `Table` прямо в методе `render()` следующим образом:

```
render() {
  // если в items будет null или undefined, то в переменную попадет пустой массив
  // своего рода защита от ошибки простым условием
  const items = this.props.items || [];

  return (
    <table>

      ...

        items.map(item => {
          return (
            <tr key={item.id} >
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.email}</td>
              <td>{item.password}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.select}</td>
              <td>{item.radio}</td>
            </tr>
         );

      ...

    </table>
  );
}
```

По всей видимости Ваш POST запрос в ответ не возвращает ожидаемую коллекцию, поэтому у Вас и позникает ошибка в коде после клика. Обратите внимание на метод `handleFormSubmit`, добавьте внутрь метода `console.log` и удостоверьтесь в том, что данные были получены в ответ:

```
fetch('api/users', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: e.target.name.value,
    email: e.target.email.value,
    password: e.target.password.value,
    radio: e.target.radio.value,
    checkbox: e.target.checkbox.checked,
    select: e.target.select.value
  })})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  // если тут данные не будут получены, то после установки forecasts упадет ошибка в Table
  console.log('Data from response: ', data);
  this.setState({ forecasts: data })  
});
```

Либо, добавьте ветку `catch` и отлавливайте ошибку, которая могла возникнуть. Смотрите Ваш POST запрос, и данные, которые он отправляет в ответе - проблема именно там.

Comment: Да я учел все ошибки, на которые Вы указали. Но продвинуться не удалось...У меня в контроллере метод POST описан так:  // POST api/users
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]NewUser user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.NewUsers.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(user);
        } и ответ приходит в виде [Object object] как быть? помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Виталий вот, это то, про что я говорил, в результат `forecasts` попадает не то, что Вы ожидаете. Обратите внимание -у вас в ответе просто объект юзера, которого Вы добавили, а не массив юзеров. Попробуйте вместо `.then(response => response.json())` написать `.then(response => response.data)`, а уже в следующем `.then(data => { ... })` ищите в объекте `data` своего `user`-а. И после этого, по  всей видимости, нужно написать так: `this.setState({ forecasts: [...this.state.forecasts, user]})` - это добавит юзера в массив без мутации. Только объект `user` нужно будет подготовить.

Comment: В data у меня падает JSon - объект моего user, которого я ввел. Я запутался. Как в data найти user от чего оттолкнуться?

Comment: @Виталий сформируйте объект `user` с полями: `id`, `email`, `name`, `password`, `select`, `radio` и добавьте указанным мной способом через spread syntax: `this.setState({ forecasts: [...this.state.forecasts, user]})` и всё будет нормально работать. Ответ у Вас в виде `[Object object]`, вот я и начал предлагать варианты. Всё просто - из ответа достать нужные поля, сформировать объект и добавить в массив, ну и перезаписать стейт после этого.

Comment: @Виталий Вам не нужно делать `response.json()` - у Вас уже в ответе объект, там будет проперти `data` в котором будет лежать объект `user`, что вы отправили с бэка. Стандартное строковое представление объекта - это строка `"[object Object]"`, при попытке преобразования оно и будет получаться, поэтому убираем `response.json()` и пишем `response.data`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное буду пробовать. User у меня в сформирован в модели как вы и сказали. А когда пробую записать this.setState({ forecasts: [...this.state.forecasts, user]}), то ошибка 'user' is not defined  no-undef. БУду искать проблему дальше

Comment: @Виталий ошибка вылазит правильно, я же написал сформируйте объект `user` с полями: `id`, `email`, `name`, `password`, `select`, `radio` и добавьте после этого его в массив. Объекта нет - поэтому ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но пока нет...(не получается...

Comment: Ошибок нет но данные в Table не появляются...

Comment: @Виталий ставьте брейкпоинт через `debugger` внутри последнего `then` и смотрите, что у Вас в результате. Думаю, что проблема достаточно примитивна, всё должно просто решаться.

Answer (score 0):

Заработало вот так:

```
 handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('api/users', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: e.target.name.value,
            email: e.target.email.value,
            password: e.target.password.value,
            radio: e.target.radio.value,
            checkbox: e.target.checkbox.checked,
            select: e.target.select.value
        })
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Data from response: ', data);
            this.setState({ forecasts: [...this.state.forecasts, data] })
        });
```

Comment: Почему говорите спасибо, если предложенный ответ вам не помог?